# Which should subscribe to view events - the presenter or the view?

Tags: mvp, view

I have some Views and Presenters. In my architecture, they have a circular dependency, so the View has a reference to the Presenter and vice-versa.

Now, which is the more commonly used:

```
class View
{
    View()
    {
        this.Event += presenter.EventHandler;
    }
}
```

or:

```
class Presenter
{
    Presenter()
    {
        view.Event += this.EventHandler;
    }
}
```

Or maybe it's pretty much the same thing? If not, what are the pros and cons of each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of coupling, *the View should not know anything about the Presenter.*  Ergo, the presenter (or some third-party object) has the responsibility of hooking up the necessary events.